# How can I summarize latent variables using PLSSEM

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, partial-least-squares

I am kinda new to PLS SEM, but I think I have the steps down and can interpret the results. However, I initially like to look at summary statistics of variables when a single variable measure a construct such as mean and standard deviations and such.

Is there a way to summarize variables such as averaging the variables in a construct between say 1 to 5, and looking at mean and SD, or is this meaningless when factor loadings, reliability/validity,etc are calculated in the PLSSEM approach?

Any helpful answer on how to best summarize variables/constructs in SEM are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It is a common practice to report a correlation table of constructs with AVE (average variance extracted) on the diagonal. You should be able to directly get the information from your software package.

It is not necessary to report means and SDs for constructs since, strictly speaking, you cannot directly observe them. If you want, you can report means and SDs for individual items.